# drawing bitmap image using background service on home screen

Tags: java, android, layout, android-windowmanager

I have a UI with ready button, when this button tapped a background service invoked. I need to set bitmap image on home screen just like a scratch on screen. Is there any way to do this without showing layout in an activity. Or if even we use layout to show that image on screen then **I need background (home, buttons and all other stuff currently opened) active**. 
[image].

I've attached above image as reference you can see what I want todo. Please help me. Your attentions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is late answer for you, but may be it can save someone else day...:)

`Permission : android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`

```
 class ScreenOverlayService extends Service {
HUDView mView;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("onStartCommand", "called....");      

    //      return android.app.Service.START_STICKY;    // don't kill service...
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mView = new HUDView(this);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
    params.setTitle("Load Average");
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(mView, params);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if(mView != null){
        ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(mView);
        mView = null;
    }
}

class HUDView extends ViewGroup {
    private Paint mLoadPaint;
    Context context;

    public HUDView(Context context_)
    {
        super(context_);
        context = context_;

        mLoadPaint = new Paint();
        mLoadPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mLoadPaint.setTextSize(10);
        mLoadPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //canvas.drawText("Hello World", 5, 15, mLoadPaint);

        // Read the image
        Bitmap markerImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic1);

        //  Draw it, centered around the given coordinates
        canvas.drawBitmap(markerImage,
                screenPoint.x - markerImage.getWidth() / 2,
                screenPoint.y - markerImage.getHeight() / 2, null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

}